error CS0263: Partial declarations of 'App' must not specify different base classes
I get this error App.xaml.cs(11,26,11,29): error CS0263: Partial declarations of 'App' must not specify different base classes.
using MauiApp1.Services.Core;
using Prism;
using Prism.Ioc;
using PrismApplication = Prism.PrismApplication;

namespace MauiApp1
{
    public partial class App : PrismApplication 
    {
        protected override async void OnInitialized()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/MainPage");
        }

        protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {
            //containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IAppInfo, AppInfoImplementation>();

            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MainPage, MainPageViewModel>();
        }
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp1.App"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>

    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()


I don't think I can replace Application with Prisme Application but that's where I have fewer errors.

Have a look at this link https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism.Maui

This error comes up because you now specify in the code-behind that App inherits from PrismApplication while in XAML you specify it as Application.
Looking at the documentation for Prism, it seems that in your MauiProgram you should do builder.UsePrismApp<App>(prism => {}) instead of the default builder.UseMauiApp<App>().
I don't see any reference to the fact that you need to inherit from PrismApplication. Also, looking through the demo project they have set up for their testing, I don't see them doing that.
Having that said, I don't have very extensive experience with Prism, but it looks like you might want to check the documentation and samples for how things have changed for usage with .NET MAUI.
